# How can i fix Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found

Tags: pascal

hi i want to run this code but it show me several errors please any one can help

```
Program Climat;
var clim: integer;
begin
Writeln('entrez degré');
Readln(clim);
if (clim < 0) then
Writeln('c est glacial ');
else 
if (clim < 30) then
Writeln('le temps est doux');
else
Writeln('trés chaud'):
end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pascal expects one statement between `then` and `else`, and a statement does not ends with a `;`. `;` is used as a separator of statements in compound statment.

To get rid of your errors do one of:

1. Remove `;` at the end of the `Writeln('c est glacial ')` and  `Writeln('le temps est doux')`
2. or use compound statements: write `then begin` and `end else` instead of just `then` and `else`.

Also after the last `Writeln` there should be `;` instead of `:`.